# Portrait mode in Emgu CV

Tags: c#, winforms, emgucv

I am creating a camera based winforms application in which I used EmguCV.

I want to capture the image in portrait mode when i click the button.

I tried:

```
cap.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 190);
cap.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 250);
```

but image is still remain in landscape mode only the dimension reduces from `640 x  480` to some `176 x 130` but i want portrait image.

So can anyone tell me how to cope up with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```
cap.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 190);
cap.SetCaptureProperty(Emgu.CV.CvEnum.CAP_PROP.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 250);
```

The code above code which you are using will only change the size of the image(captured frame) , you are not getting the exact mentioned size is probably because the Aspect Ratio is being maintained.

Now coming to portrait mode capturing , In would suggest rotating the current frame 90 deg after its captured and then re sizing it to fit the Image Box.

The code will be something like this

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();


    _capture = new Capture();   
    Application.Idle += ProcessFrame;
}

private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
{
    Image<Bgr, Byte> currentFrame = _capture.QueryFrame();
    currentFrame =currentFrame.Rotate(90,new Bgr(255,255,255),true);
    // other code to the task you want to achieve like displaying in ImageBox etc.


}
```

Check the official documentation [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.4.2/document/html/15ffee56-6db8-1c53-17c8-bceb13b7103d.htm)